# Hyper-V server 2019 looses connectivity after creating first virtual switch

Tags: networking, virtualization, hyper-v

I have multiple win srv 2019 with HV role.  Two nics in a team (switch independant and dynamic)

When installing the role of HV it ask to create a the first vswitch. I choose the my nic team interface. I loose connectivity after this even though i set the right vlan on the vswitch and go into the new vEthernet adapter that is created and assign IP on it but nothing. Checkbox allow management OS to share the network is on.

my reference for this is when i installed hyper-v on win 10 pro and i understand it creates a logical switch and interface over my physical and u assing the the vEthernet the new ip or it carries over(either way it works). this did not happen on this server.

Comment: Is your hyperv server DHCP, or statically assigned before you create the switch?  You mentioned you have multiple interfaces, perhaps the new virtual interface isn't getting an address?

Comment: nothing is using dhcp its all staic

Comment: So did you reconfigure a static IP after creating the Hyper-V Switch?

Comment: yes. its stated above as **"and assign IP on it but nothing"**